# Developing job for Flink

Tags: java, apache-flink

I am building a simple data pipeline for learning purposes. I have real time data coming from Kafka, I would like to do some transformations using Flink.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure if I understand correctly deployment options. In the the Flink docs I have found section about Docker Compose and application mode. It says that I can deploy only one job to the Flink:

> A Flink Application cluster is a dedicated cluster which runs a single job. In this case, you deploy the cluster with the job as one step, thus, there is no extra job submission needed.
> The job artifacts are included into the class path of Flink’s JVM process within the container and consist of:
>
> - your job jar, which you would normally submit to a Session cluster and
> - all other necessary dependencies or resources, not included into Flink.

> To deploy a cluster for a single job with Docker, you need to
>
> - make job artifacts available locally in all containers under /opt/flink/usrlib,
> - start a JobManager container in the Application cluster mode
> - start the required number of TaskManager containers.

On the other hand, I found examples on github using `flink-java` artifact, without running any docker image.

What is the difference and why the second option in not mentioned in Flink docs?

And, is it possible to deploy Flink job as a separate docker image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at [Demystifying Flink Deployments](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xm1X9etMXps).

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/overview/ also gives a good overview.

If you're interested in setting up a standalone cluster (without Docker or Kubernetes or YARN), see https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/overview/.

> And, is it possible to deploy Flink job as a separate docker image?

I'm not sure how to interpret this question. Are you asking if the Flink client can run in a separate image from the Flink cluster that runs the job? You could dockerize a session cluster and submit a job into that cluster from outside it. You'll find an example of that in https://github.com/apache/flink-playgrounds/blob/master/operations-playground/docker-compose.yaml.  (That operations playground is a good resource, btw.)

Another approach builds a single image that can be run as either a job manager or a task manager, with the flink client and all of its dependencies built into that image. This approach is described in https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/resource-providers/native_kubernetes/#application-mode.

It's worth noting that a lot of folks aren't doing any of this directly, and are instead relying on platforms that manage containerized Flink deployments at a higher level.

Comment: Yeah, maybe my question was not clear. But you managed to answer it - by describing the usual approach. Can you elaborate on that, especially ` the flink client and all of its dependencies built into that image.`?

Comment: I've expanded my answer. I wish I had a working example of the second approach that I could point you to, but I don't know of one. As I mentioned, many of us are relying on tooling that makes doing those steps ourselves unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks. I assume, you are reffering to k8s flink operator? I've just found out about it.

Comment: Personally, I use Ververica Platform, which has both free (as in beer) and commercial editions. Disclaimer: I work for Ververica.